# UIScrollView doesn't scroll vertically(i have a bottom bar view)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, vertical-scrolling

```
import UIKit
```

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

```
// titolo dell'annotazione selezionata proveniente dalla ViewController
var titoloStringa = ""
/*
// riferimento alla scrollView delle immagini
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

// riferimento al page control relativo alle immagini
@IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

// array che conterrà le immagini
var pageImages: [UIImage] = []

// array di optionals che conterrà istanze di UIImageView per mostrare ogni immagine nella sua relativa pagina
var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []
*/
// riferimento alla label titolo
@IBOutlet weak var titolo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scroolView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelTesto: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.labelTesto.numberOfLines = 0
    self.labelTesto.sizeToFit()    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.*/
```

}

Why doesn't the scroll vertical work? I will implement after the scrolling of images with control page. how can i do it?

Comment: what is the contentSize of the scrollView? if it is not bigger then the frame size, there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your `UIScrollView` height not more than `ViewController` height.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scroolView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        scroolView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 2300)
        scroolView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        scroolView.scrollEnabled = true

    }
}
```

Comment: i added theese lines of code e doesn't scrool :(
the possible problem can be the bottom bar?